# C++ Pointing a variable (to be filled by the user) that is defined in a struct which is inside another struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm working on *lists*. I would like to perform a variable insertion (user side) that is defined in a struct which is inside another struct.

Part of my code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



// Global variables
struct gioco {string piattaforma;
              string titolo;
              string genere;
              string sviluppatore;
              string publisher;
              struct data {int giorno;
                           int mese;               // Formato data GG/MM/AAAA
                           int anno;  };
              bool disponibile;
              gioco * recordSuccessivo; };


// Prototypes
bool stampaLista (gioco *);
gioco * aggiungiGioco (gioco *);


// MAIN Function
int main (void)
         {// Local Variables (MAIN)
          char sceltaMenu = '\0';
          gioco * puntatoreTesta = NULL;
          gioco * puntatoreCoda = NULL;
          gioco * puntatoreDeposito = NULL;


          // [more code]

          stampaLista (puntatoreTesta);

          // [more code + ASCII menu]

          cin>>sceltaMenu;

          switch (sceltaMenu)
                 {case '1':
                    puntatoreDeposito = aggiungiGioco (puntatoreTesta);
                    break;

                  // [more cases + default]
                 }


          return 0;
         }


// Other Functions
bool stampaLista (gioco * puntatoreTesta)
                 {cout<<endl<<"PIATTAFORMA"<<"\t"<<"TITOLO"<<"\t"<<"GENERE"<<"\t"<<"SVILUPPATORE"<<"\t"<<"PUBLISHER"<<"\t"<<"DATA DI USCITA"<<"\t"<<"DISPONIBILE"<<endl<<endl;

                  if (puntatoreTesta != NULL)
                     {gioco * puntatoreDeposito = NULL;
                      puntatoreDeposito = puntatoreTesta;

                      do {cout<<puntatoreDeposito -> piattaforma<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> titolo<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> genere<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> sviluppatore<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> publisher<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> gioco.data.giorno<<"/"<<puntatoreDeposito -> gioco.data.mese<<"/"<<puntatoreDeposito -> gioco.data.anno<<"\t"
                              <<puntatoreDeposito -> disponibile<<endl;
                          puntatoreDeposito++;
                         } while (puntatoreDeposito != NULL);


                      return false;
                     }
                  else
                     {cout<<"La lista e' vuota!"<<endl<<endl<<endl;


                      return true;
                     }
                 }


gioco * aggiungiGioco (gioco * puntatoreTesta)
                      {// Local Variables
                       gioco * puntatoreNuovo = new gioco;
                       puntatoreNuovo -> recordSuccessivo = NULL;


                       cout<<"NUOVO RECORD"<<endl<<endl;

                       cout<<"Piattaforma:"<<"\t";
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> piattaforma;
                       cout<<"Titolo:"<<"\t";
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> titolo;
                       cout<<"Genere:"<<"\t";
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> genere;
                       cout<<"Sviluppatore:"<<"\t";
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> sviluppatore;
                       cout<<"Publisher:"<<"\t";
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> publisher;
                       cout<<"Data di Uscita:"<<endl;
                       cin>>puntatoreNuovo -> gioco.data.giorno>>puntatoreNuovo -> gioco.data.mese>>puntatoreNuovo -> gioco.data.anno;


                       return puntatoreNuovo;
                      }
```

What I get with this, is an error of "invalid use of `struct gioco`", both in print and field filling functions, as I use the syntax `gioco.data.giorno`/`.mese`/`.anno` to access these nested variables by pointing to them with the `new node` constructor pointer.

This is almost surely a problem of wrong syntax, though I cannot see the right way to work this out.
Any suggestions on how to achieve what am I trying to?

Comment: You defined a struct inside struct but you didn't assign a vsriable name to that struct. It is similary to writing `int;` inside the main struct. `struct data` is just a type.

Comment: Aren't `gioco` and `data` the structs names?

Comment: They are struct names or you can call them `types`. You never access `gico` fields by writing `gico.field_name`, you define a variable of type `gico`: `gico var;` and then you access the fields of `var` by `var.field_name`. Same should be with `struct data`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me that  :)

Comment: No problem! You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your struct in this way:

```
 // Global variables
 struct gioco {string piattaforma;
          string titolo;
          string genere;
          string sviluppatore;
          string publisher;
          struct data {int giorno;
                       int mese;               // Formato data GG/MM/AAAA
                       int anno;  } data_field;
          bool disponibile;
          gioco * recordSuccessivo; };
```

And then you can access it:

```
                   gioco* puntatoreNuovo = new gioco;
                   puntatoreNuovo->recordSuccessivo = NULL;

                   ......

                   cout<<"Data di Uscita:"<<endl;
                   cin>>puntatoreNuovo->data_field.giorno >> puntatoreNuovo->data_field.mese >> puntatoreNuovo->data_field.anno;
                   ......
```

Comment: So don't I have to do that even with `struct gioco`, since we are talking of nested structs?

Comment: Like `struct gioco { /* ... */ } gioco_field` to access them by `gioco_field.data_field.giorno`/`.mese`/`.anno`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. There is no point to define internal struct since no one can access it but the `gico` struct.

Comment: @LorenzoMaffii I am adding a correction. The point of defineng struct internally is to make it visible only to `giko`, this method is comonly used in C++ for encapsulation. But since you are using structs more like C structs and not C++, then there is no real reason for that.

Comment: @LorenzoMaffii No. You just use then as a container to store related properties. Without constructors, distructors and different methods.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am using structs more like C structs and not like C++ ones"? You mean the fact that I declare them starting with the keyword `struct` `type` and not only just writing their `type`?